# How to Restrict Fetching records in HTTPGET API for every new request

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, callout

How can I restrict records in HTTPGET API(Standard API), for every new request(when I hit the url in postman) I have to send new data.

For Example: For the 1st request I am fetching 10 records with specified request parameters, and for next request I don't want to send previous 10 records.

is there any possibility, can someone help me.

Comment: So, are you using a standard REST API, or an Apex REST API?

Comment: i am using Standard API

Comment: maybe you can try using `List Views` resource, as suggested on this article's answer: [Implement pagination on APEX REST Endpoint without using OFFSET or LastRecordID](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/353170/implement-pagination-on-apex-rest-endpoint-without-using-offset-or-lastrecordid)